# Error: JavaFX runtime components are missing, and are required to run this application

Tags: java, ant, javafx-2

I tried to build the application using javafx ant build, generated jar file.
But when I run the jar file, issue:

> Error: JavaFX runtime components are missing, and are required to run this application.

The `javafx-class-path: libs/h2.jar libs/jfxrt.jar libs/log4j.jar`

Running the JAR file using:

```
java -jar app.jar
```

What could it be?

Comment: How are you running the generated JAR file? What's the CLASSPATH? Where is the JavaFX JAR file? http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/deployment/javafx_ant_task_reference.htm

Comment: javafx-class-path: libs/h2.jar libs/jfxrt.jar libs/log4j.jar

Comment: running: java -jar app.jar

Comment: See related question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56894627/how-to-fix-error-javafx-runtime-components-are-missing-and-are-required-to-ru/58498686#58498686

Answer (score -1):

I was able to reproduce your issue on windows machine (with java8 64bit version).

One simple work around could be: try reinstalling java again.

Another could be: copying jre/lib/jfxrt.jar to jre/lib/ext/jfxrt.jar