# How to fix "Error: JavaFX runtime components are missing, and are required to run this application"?

Tags: javafx-11

My JavaFX application is running perfectly well from source but When I'm compiling to a single jar file I get error :

> **Error: JavaFX runtime components are missing, and are required to run this application.**

I'm using Maven as my repository manager and My install with Maven is successful.

Note: In my IntelliJ build artifact I can see that IntelliJ include JavaFX and all its libraries

Comment: Duplicated of [Maven Shade JavaFX runtime components are missing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52653836/maven-shade-javafx-runtime-components-are-missing)

Comment: This answer is detailed and helped me: https://stackoverflow.com/a/70809214/10946427

Answer (score 29):

a) For my maven project the trick was to use an **extra starter class** that does not inherit from javafx.application.Application:

```
public class GUIStarter {

    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        GUI.main(args);
    }

}
```

The JavaFx dependencies are included in my pom.xml as follows:

```
<!-- JavaFx -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-base</artifactId>
            <version>12</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-controls</artifactId>
            <version>12</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-graphics </artifactId>
            <version>12</version>
            <classifier>win</classifier>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-fxml</artifactId>
            <version>12</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-web</artifactId>
            <version>12</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-media</artifactId>
            <version>12</version>
        </dependency>

         <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-swing</artifactId>
            <version>12</version>
        </dependency>
```

In order to include fxml files in your build, you might need to define them as resource:

```
!-- define JavaFx files as resources to include them in the jar -->
<resource>
      <directory>${basedir}/src/main/java/foo/baa/view</directory>
      <filtering>false</filtering>  
      <targetPath>foo/baa/view</targetPath>            
</resource>
```

b) As an alternative, an extra maven plugin "javafx-maven-plugin" could be used to build the javafx appication, see example project at https://openjfx.io/openjfx-docs/#maven (This did not work for me. I have several pom files and want to reference the javafx dependencies in a sub project. My main class could not be found by the javafx-maven-plugin.)

Comment: The extra starter class worked for me. Using Netbeans 11.3, I created a new project using "FXML JavaFX Maven Archetype (Gluon)" which could build but not run. The question is "why does this work?"

Comment: @Doc See info about "sun.launcher.LauncherHelper" here: https://mail.openjdk.java.net/pipermail/openjfx-dev/2018-June/021977.html

Comment: @Stefan, Can you please give me a sample project link where it works?

Comment: @Md. Asaduzzaman
Nope. I do not use Java any more and have nothing online from the old projects. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

STEP 1 - In your src. [Step 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/csdVY.jpg) add "extra" main I named Launcher as you can see in Step2 image.

STEP 2 - After in the "extra" class create a main and in that call the main of the MainClassJavaFx
[Step 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JkhN5.jpg)

STEP 3 - From project structure add new artifact and select the "extra class" as main and relocate the MANIFEST folder to src and not resources.
[Step 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WpRLx.jpg)

STEP 4 - Add all dll from javafx sdk from your folder
[Step 4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qpC2v.jpg)

STEP 5 - Build artifact

This should works.

Answer (score 0):

1 STEP is to create a class name it like you want it should be Main class that would start your program, paste there (in psvm) like GUI.main(args).2 STEP is go to Artifacts and add there all .dll from jfx/bin/ 3 STEP is put the META-INF to src .4 STEP is build artifacts and try to run.But the reason what i have is when i run this (my progr contains sql db) the sqldb creates in running folder but i dont see the main window

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

In Java 11 the JavaFX components have been removed into their own SDK, so when you run it won't be able to find them in the runtime.

The JavaFX page has the instructions to get it going: https://openjfx.io/openjfx-docs/#install-javafx

In short, you have to compile / run by adding the javafx modules in, either as options passed on the command line, or using a modular project.

I found that the modular project with Maven and IntelliJ worked best for me. https://openjfx.io/openjfx-docs/#IDE-Intellij

In the modular method you have a `module-info.java` file that describes all the modules that your project "requires", and allows you to "open" them to other modules. If you have a bunch of Maven dependencies you have to add them in the requires list too though. (IntelliJ can make this easy - find the error about no requires in the code and alt-enter)

Once everything was working with modules etc, I had to make a Fat Jar using I think the Maven shade plugin, to put everything together. Then it would work running the jar from the command line.

However, after getting my Java 11 code @#$%@# working after 2 days of pain, I went back to Java 8 (using correto SDK for latest version) as Java 11 doesn't have packaging and IntelliJ can't do it for you.

Comment: JavaFx is in my module

Comment: I have resolved that issue. Maven is repository is not including my libraries during compiling to a single jar file. I had to stop using maven for the compilation and move my source to different project then manually compile it myself