# JAR file won't run

Tags: java, maven, javafx, jar, runnable

I recently wrote a simple calculator using Maven and JavaFX, nothing special. The code runs without problems, all operations occur without problems - I try to compile the jar file, I compile it, but when I try to run it, nothing happens, the process does not even appear in the manager.

I tried to run through the console, if the versions match JDK and JRE are the same, I attached the screen. At startup, it gives such an error, I tried to fix it, googled it, tried everything, there were no problems with connecting JavaFX and there weren’t. Then it knocks out an error that it cannot find the main class, it also knocked out an error about the unknown location of the manifest file. I corrected all these mistakes and did everything that was required of me - as a result, absolutely nothing. After one mistake another, after another a third, then something else pops up and in the end, I don’t understand anything.

[open jar in cmd](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PnQH8.png)

[version jdk jre](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sbEjH.png)

**main class - application**

```java
package com.example.simplecalculator;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

import java.io.IOException;

public class HelloApplication extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws IOException {
        FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader(HelloApplication.class.getResource("hello-view.fxml"));
        Scene scene = new Scene(fxmlLoader.load(), 322, 430);
        stage.setTitle("Калькулятор");
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.setResizable(false);
        stage.setAlwaysOnTop(true);
        stage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

**fxml file**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.Cursor?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TextField?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.text.Font?>
<?import javafx.scene.text.Text?>

<AnchorPane maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="436.0" prefWidth="322" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/17" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="com.example.simplecalculator.HelloController">
    <TextField fx:id="calculateField" editable="false" layoutX="32.0" layoutY="41.0" prefHeight="62.0" prefWidth="257.0" promptText="Введите число..." style="-fx-background-color: #DCDCDC;">
        <font>
            <Font size="27.0" />
        </font>
    </TextField>
    <Text fx:id="textMessage" fill="#6b6363" layoutX="33.0" layoutY="33.0" strokeType="OUTSIDE" strokeWidth="0.0" text="">
        <font>
            <Font name="Arial" size="12.0" />
        </font>
    </Text>
    <Button fx:id="Button1" layoutX="36.0" layoutY="119.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#OneButtonClick" prefHeight="46.0" prefWidth="54.0" style="-fx-background-color: #DCDCDC;" text="1" textFill="#595959">
        <font>
            <Font name="Arial" size="12.0" />
        </font>
        <cursor>
            <Cursor fx:constant="HAND" />
        </cursor></Button>
    <Button layoutX="102.0" layoutY="119.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#SecondButtonClick" prefHeight="46.0" prefWidth="54.0" style="-fx-background-color: #DCDCDC;" text="2" textFill="#595959">
        <font>
            <Font name="Arial" size="12.0" />
        </font>
        <cursor>
            <Cursor fx:constant="HAND" />
        </cursor></Button>
    <Button layoutX="166.0" layoutY="118.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#ThirdButtonClick" prefHeight="46.0" prefWidth="54.0" style="-fx-background-color: #DCDCDC;" text="3" textFill="#595959">
        <font>
            <Font name="Arial" size="12.0" />
        </font>
        <cursor>
            <Cursor fx:constant="HAND" />
        </cursor></Button>
    <Button layoutX="36.0" layoutY="180.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#FourthButtonClick" prefHeight="46.0" prefWidth="54.0" style="-fx-background-color: #DCDCDC;" text="4" textFill="#595959">
        <font>
            <Font name="Arial" size="12.0" />
        </font>
        <cursor>
            <Cursor fx:constant="HAND" />
        </cursor></Button>
    <Button layoutX="102.0" layoutY="180.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#FifthButtonClick" prefHeight="46.0" prefWidth="54.0" style="-fx-background-color: #DCDCDC;" text="5" textFill="#595959">
        <font>
            <Font name="Arial" size="12.0" />
        </font>
        <cursor>
            <Cursor fx:constant="HAND" />
        </cursor></Button>
    <Button layoutX="166.0" layoutY="180.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#SixthButtonClick" prefHeight="46.0" prefWidth="54.0" style="-fx-background-color: #DCDCDC;" text="6" textFill="#595959">
        <font>
            <Font name="Arial" size="12.0" />
        </font>
        <cursor>
            <Cursor fx:constant="HAND" />
        </cursor></Button>
    <Button layoutX="37.0" layoutY="242.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#SeventhButtonClick" prefHeight="46.0" prefWidth="54.0" style="-fx-background-color: #DCDCDC;" text="7" textFill="#595959">
        <font>
            <Font name="Arial" size="12.0" />
        </font>
        <cursor>
            <Cursor fx:constant="HAND" />
        </cursor></Button>
    <Button layoutX="102.0" layoutY="242.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#EigthButtonClick" prefHeight="46.0" prefWidth="54.0" style="-fx-background-color: #DCDCDC;" text="8" textFill="#595959">
        <font>
            <Font name="Arial" size="12.0" />
        </font>
        <cursor>
            <Cursor fx:constant="HAND" />
        </cursor></Button>
    <Button layoutX="166.0" layoutY="242.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#NinthButtonClick" prefHeight="46.0" prefWidth="54.0" style="-fx-background-color: #DCDCDC;" text="9" textFill="#595959">
        <font>
            <Font name="Arial" size="12.0" />
        </font>
        <cursor>
            <Cursor fx:constant="HAND" />
        </cursor></Button>
    <Button layoutX="37.0" layoutY="303.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#ZeroButtonClick" prefHeight="46.0" prefWidth="54.0" style="-fx-background-color: #DCDCDC;" text="0" textFill="#595959">
        <font>
            <Font name="Arial" size="12.0" />
        </font>
        <cursor>
            <Cursor fx:constant="HAND" />
        </cursor></Button>
    <Button layoutX="102.0" layoutY="363.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#Result" prefHeight="46.0" prefWidth="182.0" style="-fx-background-color: #DCDCDC;" text="=" textFill="#595959">
        <font>
            <Font name="Arial" size="17.0" />
        </font>
        <cursor>
            <Cursor fx:constant="HAND" />
        </cursor></Button>
    <Button layoutX="166.0" layoutY="303.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#CButtonClick" prefHeight="46.0" prefWidth="54.0" style="-fx-background-color: #DCDCDC;" text="C" textFill="#595959">
        <font>
            <Font name="Arial" size="12.0" />
        </font>
        <cursor>
            <Cursor fx:constant="HAND" />
        </cursor></Button>
    <Button layoutX="102.0" layoutY="303.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#deleteButton" prefHeight="46.0" prefWidth="54.0" style="-fx-background-color: #DCDCDC;" text="←" textFill="#595959">
        <font>
            <Font name="Arial" size="17.0" />
        </font>
        <cursor>
            <Cursor fx:constant="HAND" />
        </cursor>
    </Button>
    <Button layoutX="230.0" layoutY="180.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#minusButton" prefHeight="46.0" prefWidth="54.0" style="-fx-background-color: #DCDCDC;" text="–" textFill="#595959">
        <font>
            <Font name="Arial Bold" size="17.0" />
        </font>
        <cursor>
            <Cursor fx:constant="HAND" />
        </cursor>
    </Button>
    <Button layoutX="230.0" layoutY="242.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#multiplicationButton" prefHeight="46.0" prefWidth="54.0" style="-fx-background-color: #DCDCDC;" text="*" textFill="#595959">
        <font>
            <Font name="Arial" size="17.0" />
        </font>
        <cursor>
            <Cursor fx:constant="HAND" />
        </cursor>
    </Button>
    <Button layoutX="230.0" layoutY="303.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#segmentationButton" prefHeight="46.0" prefWidth="54.0" style="-fx-background-color: #DCDCDC;" text="/" textFill="#595959">
        <font>
            <Font name="Arial" size="17.0" />
        </font>
        <cursor>
            <Cursor fx:constant="HAND" />
        </cursor>
    </Button>
    <Button layoutX="230.0" layoutY="118.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#plusButton" prefHeight="46.0" prefWidth="54.0" style="-fx-background-color: #DCDCDC;" text="+" textFill="#595959">
        <font>
            <Font name="Arial" size="17.0" />
        </font>
        <cursor>
            <Cursor fx:constant="HAND" />
        </cursor>
    </Button>
    <Text fx:id="textMessage2" fill="#6b6363" layoutX="39.0" layoutY="19.0" strokeType="OUTSIDE" strokeWidth="0.0">
        <font>
            <Font name="Arial" size="12.0" />
        </font>
    </Text>
    <Button layoutX="37.0" layoutY="363.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#helpButton" prefHeight="46.0" prefWidth="54.0" style="-fx-background-color: #f4f4f4;" text="Help!" textAlignment="RIGHT" textFill="#595959">
        <font>
            <Font name="Arial" size="12.0" />
        </font>
        <cursor>
            <Cursor fx:constant="HAND" />
        </cursor>
    </Button>
    <Text layoutX="137.0" layoutY="425.0" opacity="0.2" strokeType="OUTSIDE" strokeWidth="0.0" text="Версия 1.0.0" wrappingWidth="102.936767578125">
        <font>
            <Font size="9.0" />
        </font>
    </Text>
</AnchorPane>
```

**controller**

```java
package com.example.simplecalculator;

import javafx.event.Event;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.text.Text;

public class HelloController {

    public int num;
    public int result;
    static int calculation;

    @FXML
    TextField calculateField;
    @FXML
    Text textMessage;
    @FXML
    Text textMessage2;

    @FXML
    public void operation(){
        switch (calculation) {
            case 1 -> { // +
                result = num + Integer.parseInt(calculateField.getText());
                calculateField.setText(Integer.toString(result));
            }
            case 2 -> { // -
                result = num - Integer.parseInt(calculateField.getText());
                calculateField.setText(Integer.toString(result));
            }
            case 3 -> { // *
                result = num * Integer.parseInt(calculateField.getText());
                calculateField.setText(Integer.toString(result));
            }
            case 4 -> { // /
                result = num / Integer.parseInt(calculateField.getText());
                calculateField.setText(Integer.toString(result));
            }
        }
    }

    @FXML
    public void ClearMethod(){
        calculateField.clear();
    }

    public void initialize(){
        calculateField.setOnKeyTyped(Event::consume);
        calculateField.setOnKeyPressed(Event::consume);
    }

    @FXML
    public void pNumbers(){
        String check = calculateField.getText();
        if(check.length() >=  11){
            textMessage.setText("Слишком большое число!");
            return;
        }
        textMessage.setText("Результат:");
    }

    @FXML
    protected void OneButtonClick() {
        calculateField.setText(calculateField.getText() + "1");
    }

    @FXML
    protected void SecondButtonClick() {
        calculateField.setText(calculateField.getText() + "2");
    }

    @FXML
    protected void ThirdButtonClick() {
        calculateField.setText(calculateField.getText() + "3");
    }

    @FXML
    protected void FourthButtonClick() {
        calculateField.setText(calculateField.getText() + "4");

    }

    @FXML
    protected void FifthButtonClick() {
        calculateField.setText(calculateField.getText() + "5");

    }

    @FXML
    protected void SixthButtonClick() {
        calculateField.setText(calculateField.getText() + "6");

    }

    @FXML
    protected void SeventhButtonClick() {
        calculateField.setText(calculateField.getText() + "7");

    }

    @FXML
    protected void EigthButtonClick() {
        calculateField.setText(calculateField.getText() + "8");

    }

    @FXML
    protected void NinthButtonClick() {
        calculateField.setText(calculateField.getText() + "9");

    }

    @FXML
    protected void ZeroButtonClick() {
        calculateField.setText(calculateField.getText() + "0");

    }

    @FXML
    protected void CButtonClick() {
        ClearMethod();
        textMessage.setText("");
        textMessage.setVisible(true);
        textMessage2.setVisible(false);
    }

    @FXML
    protected void deleteButton() {
        String value = calculateField.getText();
        int length = value.length();

        if(length > 0){
            StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder(value);
            builder.deleteCharAt(length-1);
            calculateField.setText(builder.toString());
        }
    }

    @FXML
    protected void plusButton() {
        pNumbers();
        try {
            num = Integer.parseInt(calculateField.getText());
            calculation = 1;
            calculateField.setText("");
            textMessage.setText(num + " +");
        } catch(NumberFormatException e){
            textMessage.setVisible(false);
            textMessage2.setText("Макс. значение для ввода равно 2,147,483,647! \n Измените число!");
            return;
        }
    }

    @FXML
    protected void minusButton(){
        pNumbers();
        try {
            num = Integer.parseInt(calculateField.getText());
            calculation = 2;
            calculateField.setText("");
            textMessage.setText(num + " -");
        } catch(NumberFormatException e){
            textMessage.setVisible(false);
            textMessage2.setText("Макс. значение для ввода равно 2,147,483,647! \n Измените число!");
            return;
        }
    }

    @FXML
    protected void multiplicationButton(){
        pNumbers();
        try {
            num = Integer.parseInt(calculateField.getText());
            calculation = 3;
            calculateField.setText("");
            textMessage.setText(num + " *");
        } catch(NumberFormatException e){
            textMessage.setVisible(false);
            textMessage2.setText("Макс. значение для ввода равно 2,147,483,647! \n Измените число!");
            return;
        }
    }

    @FXML
    protected void segmentationButton() {
        pNumbers();
        try {
            num = Integer.parseInt(calculateField.getText());
            calculation = 4;
            calculateField.setText("");
            textMessage.setText(num + " /");
        } catch(NumberFormatException e){
            textMessage.setVisible(false);
            textMessage2.setText("Макс. значение для ввода равно 2,147,483,647! \n Измените число!");
            return;
        }
    }

    @FXML
    protected void helpButton() {
        pNumbers();
    }

    @FXML
    protected void Result(){
        operation();
        textMessage.setText("Результат: ");
    }
}
```

**xml-file**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>SimpleCalculator</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>SimpleCalculator</name>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <junit.version>5.8.2</junit.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-controls</artifactId>
            <version>18</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-fxml</artifactId>
            <version>18</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
            <version>${junit.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
            <version>${junit.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.10.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>18</source>
                    <target>18</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
                <artifactId>javafx-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>0.0.8</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <!-- Default configuration for running with: mvn clean javafx:run -->
                        <id>default-cli</id>
                        <configuration>
                            <mainClass>com.example.simplecalculator/com.example.simplecalculator.HelloApplication
                            </mainClass>
                            <launcher>app</launcher>
                            <jlinkZipName>app</jlinkZipName>
                            <jlinkImageName>app</jlinkImageName>
                            <noManPages>true</noManPages>
                            <stripDebug>true</stripDebug>
                            <noHeaderFiles>true</noHeaderFiles>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Comment: I would have a closer look at the CMD error message.

Comment: For reference, simpler command line examples are cited [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71288497/230513) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69651076/230513).

Comment: So, I was able to make my JavaFX/Maven project work via the command line by following [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56894627/how-to-fix-error-javafx-runtime-components-are-missing-and-are-required-to-ru) and [this example](http://fxapps.blogspot.com/2020/11/creating-fat-jars-for-javafx.html)

Comment: Also try the `javafx-maven-plugin` command `mvn javafx:run`,  seen [here](https://openjfx.io/openjfx-docs/#maven).

Comment: I'll try and post the results later.

Answer (score 3):

Creating jar files for JavaFX programs is not the reccomended packaging practice anyway due to several issues with them. Have a look here  https://stackoverflow.com/tags/javafx/info under the headline "packaging".